# Cannot get second message using ReceiveAsync() in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I got in trouble using ReceiveAsync().

I want to get messages from the Server.

The first message was received, however, i cannot get any message from the second.

I am still trying to find any solution, but i can't.

Part of my Client source is below :

```
    public void Recieve_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Socket _client = (Socket)sender;
        Msg _Msg = (Msg)e.UserToken;
        _Msg.SetLength(e.Buffer);
        _Msg.InitData();

        if (_client.Connected && e.BytesTransferred > 0)
        {

             ...

             Do sth

             ...


             _client.ReceiveAsync(e);  

        }
        else //No Message
        {
            //Connection_Timer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Did I make any stupid mistake.

If then, plz let me know.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that TCP is message-based. It is not. TCP offers you a stream of bytes. Reads can read any amount greater than zero. Your code has to deal with that fact.